# C++ Right way to define function's default arguments

Tags: c++

As far I understood the right place to put the default parameters is the declaration file (*.h). So for example:

test.cpp

```
void print_a(int a){
    std::cout << a;
}
```

test.h

```
void print_a(int a = 5);
```

In this case I could have a third file. Where I can run print_a() with or without parameters.

main.cpp

```
#include test.h
int main(void)
{
    print_a();
    print_a(6);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, what if inside test.cpp I have another function that wants to use print_a without parameters? The compiler tells me that the function has too few arguments.

How do you do it then ?

Comment: Did you include `test.h` in `test.cpp`?

Comment: Are you making sure to `#include "test.h"` at the top of `test.cpp`?

Comment: [Works just fine here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MI3puT4KpU8u1Z6A)

Comment: Wait, did you try or did you just assume it was an error?  You should at least try before asking.

Comment: Post a more complete excerpt of `test.cpp` so we can see how you're doing it.

Comment: The error message should be clear about where the error is coming from.

Comment: You are right guys. I am sorry, after some time I really thought that the problem was somehow related to that. But it was another thing. Should I remove the question?

Comment: you could remove the "includes are ignored" comment and add the includes that you actual have in your code (if any)

Comment: Okay I changed a bit the question. So now what is clearly missing is the #include test.h in the test.cpp. i guess it can be helpful for people that run into the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the declaration of the function, with the default value, in test.cpp. The best way to do that is to `#include` test.h in test.cpp.